# Formatting number with comma separation, NO TO_CHAR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, format, numbers

Can somebody suggest to me how a number can be displayed using comma separation without using the TO_CHAR function?

NUMBER 3455678.05 should be displayed as 3,455,678.05
NUMBER 3455678 should be displayed as 3,455,678

Comment: If you don't want to or can't use the perfect tool for the job, you'll have to give a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Without using TO_CHAR(), it's not possible, unless it can be handled in the client program.

For example, in SQL*Plus, you can do:

```
set numformat 999,999,999,999,999.00
```

but that's not a complete example, as 3455678.05 would print as 3,455,678.05, but, 3455678 would print as 3,455,678.00.

The correct solution is to use TO_CHAR() function, along with setting NLS_TERRITORY and/or NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS to properly format output.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I think "the correct solution" is to let the client program handle display issues, as you show with the SQL*Plus example.  It's all about *separation of concerns*.

Answer (score 0):

Display formating is something which should be done in your application or presentation layer, not via SQL.

If you insist on doing it, then as Mark J. Bobak says, to_char is your only option.